# Put image+text inside comboBox windows 8 app

Tags: image, combobox, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to place `image+text` inside my `comboBox` in my app. How can I do this?

Comment: You may have to extend the combo box and override the default XAML (I'm assuming this is XAML) templates.
Do you need any further help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using this using appropriate values:

```
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image/>
                            <TextBlock/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```